# On the product of two finitely generated $\Omega$-algebras.

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, finitely-generated

Let $\Omega$ be a signature without predicate symbols and let $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ be two finitely generated $\Omega$-algebras. Consider their product in the category of all $\Omega$-algebras, let it be $\mathcal{A} \times \mathcal{B}$.

> Is it true that $\mathcal{A} \times \mathcal{B}$ is also finitely generated?

I know that it is true for monoids, for example. But maybe there exists a simple example why it is not true for an arbitrary two finitely generated $\Omega$-algebras? Or is it always true?

Comment: Please add what $\Omega$ is. Is it a signature?

Comment: @Martin Brandenburg Yes, it is a signature. Without predicate symbols, because we talk about algebras. I will add this, thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is an explicit counterexample (covered by the theorem cited in Martin's answer). Let $N$ be the semigroup of natural numbers (excluding $0$) under addition. This is finitely generated by $\{ 1 \}$. On the other hand, $N \times N$ is the semigroup of pairs of natural numbers (excluding $0$) under addition. This semigroup is not finitely generated, because there are infinitely many pairs of the form $(1, n)$ or $(n, 1)$ and they are indecomposable; they can't be written as a nontrivial sum of other pairs at all.

Answer (score 5):

When $A,B$ are two finitely generated monoids, then $A \times B$ is finitely generated because it is generated by $\{1\} \times F \,\cup\, E \times \{1\}$, where $E \subseteq A$, $F \subseteq B$ are finite generating sets. This hints that the claim might be false for semigroups, which lack a neutral element.

> **Theorem.** If $A,B$ are two infinite semigroups, then $A \times B$ is finitely generated iff $A$ and $B$ are finitely generated and $A^2 = A$, $B^2 = B$ (i.e., every element of $A$ is decomposable, the same for $B$).

This is Theorem 2.1 in *Generators and relations of direct products of semigroups* by E. F. Robertson, N. Ruskuc, J. Wiegold ([pdf](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1998-350-07/S0002-9947-98-02074-1/S0002-9947-98-02074-1.pdf)). In particular, there are lots of finitely generated semigroups whose product is not finitely generated (see Qiaochu's answer for an explicit one).

The proof of the Theorem also gives the estimate $\mathrm{rank}(A \times B) \leq 4 \cdot \mathrm{rank}(A) \cdot \mathrm{rank}(B)$ if $A \times B$ is finitely generated (which is much "worse" than the case of monoids).

More general questions of this type (*When is a direct product finitely generated / presented?*) are covered in *Finiteness properties of direct products of algebraic structures* by P. Mayr and N. Ruskuc ([pdf](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021869317305562)). In particular, Theorem 2.2 in that paper gives a generalization of the result for monoids, groups, rings, modules, Lie algebras.

It is worthwhile to mention that  the following is always true: if $A,B$ are finitely generated, then their coproduct $A \sqcup B$ is finitely generated. Actually, any finite colimit of finitely generated objects is finitely generated. You can either prove this directly with generating sets, or prove it in a much more categorical setting where $A$ is called [finitely generated](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/finitely+generated+object) when $\hom(A,-)$ preserves filtered colimits of monomorphisms. Then the result follows from the well-known fact that filtered colimits commute with finite limits (in $\mathbf{Set}$). From this perspective, it is also not a coincidence that finitely generated objects are not closed under finite limits, even under binary products: there is nothing we can say about $\hom(A \times B,-)$ in general, the arrow direction is "wrong". Of course, the product of two finitely cogenerated objects is again finitely cogenerated. If $A,B$ are *monoids*, however, we can describe $\hom(A \times B,C)$ as the subset of $\hom(A,C) \times \hom(B,C)$ consisting of element-wise commuting homomorphisms, and this is how you get a categorical proof that $A \times B$ is finitely generated when $A,B$ are.

Answer (score 4):

The example that jumps out at me is the set of natural numbers $\Bbb N$ equipped with the successor operation (so $\Omega$ just has a unary function symbol). The finitely generated $\Omega$-algebras are the ones that decompose into a union of finitely many orbits of this function (by orbit I mean a set which is obtained by repeatedly applying this function to some value). In this case $\Bbb N$ is generated by $1$, but its direct product with itself is $\Bbb N^2$ equipped with the operation $(a, b) \mapsto (a + 1, b + 1)$, which is very far from being finitely generated - the subalgebra generated by a point is the infinite diagonal starting from that point.

I know more model theory than universal algebra, which is perhaps why this example appeals to me (it's a pretty radical departure from the "usual" algebraic structures like groups and monoids). I think it's quite nice, and I find it easy to visualise. It is somewhat similar to the other answers (which are both excellent!) but I post it in the hope that someone else will find it useful.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what "orbit" means here if the operation isn't required to be invertible. The example is a nice one though.

Comment: I like the geometric picture here. $\mathbb{N}$ has just one "direction". $\mathbb{N}^2$ has a lot of "directions".

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, that's a good point, thank you!